# Do I need to set tcpip_socket = true to allow remote connections to a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to enable remote connections to my postgresql 9.1 db running on ubuntu 12.04.

[This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postgresql-remote-access-or-connection/) tutorial says to "set tcpip_socket to true" -- but it is for a centos server. I am on ubuntu.

I don't see this line included in my postgresql.conf.

```
$cat /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf | grep tcpip_socket
```

And when I add it in, I get the error:

```
 "FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "tcpip_socket"
```

Do I need to tell postgres 9.1 to "turn on" tcp_ip connections if its running on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you should need is:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and then to modify `pg_hba.conf` to permit connections from the desired source.

This is stated in the comments on the (very old) article you were reading.

Try using the main PostgreSQL documentation, or up to date tutorials, in future.

See:

- [Connection and authentication settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html)
- [Client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)

Comment: In my humble opinion, listen_addresses should be set to this by default. Because first I thought it was my VPN that was the issue. So I ran netcat to see if I could get data through. Then I thought it was UFW that was the issue, but the tcp/udp ports 5432 were already open. Then I thought shorewall was issue, but couldn't be since it was through VPN. I already had pg_hba.conf configured to accept an connections within VPN. And finally when I was about to lose hope, I came across this listen_addresses flag, which worked.

Comment: It's an ease of use vs secure-by-default tradeoff. Servers shouldn't listen on outside interfaces by default - even if it's more convenient if they do.

Comment: Note: The official Docker image uses `listen_addresses = '*'` per default. Also it `trust`s any host (ignoring passwords).

Comment: @luckydonald *sigh*. That's very silly of them.